# Three combination of dimension array in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do I  create three combinations of dimension array in C#?, I am getting error message

> index was outside of the bounds of the array.

```
foreach (XmlNode RegexExpression in XmlDataAccess.GetElementList(RefFile, "//regex"))
{
    xRefList.Add(RegexExpression.InnerText);
}

foreach (XmlNode RegexExpression in XmlDataAccess.GetElementList(RefFile, "//word"))
{
    WordList.Add(RegexExpression.InnerText);
}
foreach (XmlNode RegexExpression in XmlDataAccess.GetElementList(RefFile, "//title"))
{
    TitleList.Add(RegexExpression.InnerText);
}

ArrayList xRefResult = MainDocumentPart_Framework.getReferenceContent(FileName, xRefList);
ArrayList TitleResult = MainDocumentPart_Framework.getReferenceContent(FileName, TitleList);
ArrayList WordResult = MainDocumentPart_Framework.getReferenceContent(FileName, WordList);


var FinalResult = from first in TitleResult.ToArray()
                  from second in WordList.ToArray()
                  from third in xRefResult.ToArray()
                  select new[] { first, second, third };

foreach (var Item in FinalResult)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Item.ToString());

    //I like to view show, all the combination of arrays
    //first1, second1, third1
    //first1, second1, third2
    //first1, second1, third3 ...........
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code are you getting the error in?

Comment: Each `item` in the last `foreach` block is actually an array -- so you probably don't want to just turn it into a string. You'll need a nested loop.

`foreach (var Item in FinalResult)
{   
   foreach(var innerItem in Item)
   {
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(innerItem.ToString());
   }

}`

That said, you probably don't want to use a messagebox to display it. I'm sure you know that, though.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i would like to show "                        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(item); //i mean combined of "first[1] second[1] third[1] \n first[1] second[1] third[2]" like this

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what kind of output you want, but I'll try to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply., its working fine, but i have another doubt, how to get name of array? foreach(var innerItem in Item) {i++ System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(innerItem.Name + innerItem.ToString());}, how to get innerItem.name currently im doing, if (i == 1){System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("title");
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(innerItem);}if (i == 2){System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("word");
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(innerItem);}
if (i == 3){System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("xref");
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(innerItem);}

Comment: Trashing data around with ArrayList and ToArray isn't very productive.  FinalResult is now an `IEnumerable<Object[]>` as far as I can tell. Consider defining a `class` first, or at least let strings be strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what kind of output you're after, and I don't think you need to use LINQ for this.

```
string outputStr = "";

for(int x = 0;x<xRefList.Count;x++)
{
  for(int y = 0;y<WordList.Count;y++)
  {
     for(int z = 0;z<TitleList.Count;z++)
    {
        outputStr += xRefList[x] + " " + WordList[y] + " " + TitleList[z] + "\n";
    }

  }
}

MessageBox.Show(outputStr);
```

Would something like this work?